# show next input after typing in the first input

Tags: jquery, input, hide, show

Here's my javascript:

```
$('#2').hide();

$("input").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if($(this).val().match()) {
        $('#2').show();
    } else {
        $('#2').hide();
    }
});
```

In my html I have 5 inputs. I want to hide all the 4 inputs so when I enter a value in the #1 input it shows #2 empty input if I enter a value in #2 input it show #3 empty input etc...

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/L7ebh/

Comment: have you tried anything at all? if so, where are you getting an error?

Comment: the code that i have it only allow to hide one input.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/L7ebh/15/

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below - (Add id="1" to the first input)

```
$('#2, #3, #4, #5').hide();

$("input").keyup(function () { 
   var value = $(this).val();
   var nextid = $(this).attr("id");
   nextid++;
   if($(this).val().match()) {
     $('#' + nextid).show();
   } else {
     $('#' + nextid).hide();
   }
});
```

Note - I would hide the inputs using display:none with CSS so they show up hidden when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for. You will need to have some extra CSS and I'm making some pretty huge assumptions based on your markup...or lack thereof.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7ebh/16/

I left in comments so you could understand what is going on.

It's important to note that using numbers as ID's is a really bad idea and not valid. I used alternate ID's in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

http://jsfiddle.net/L7ebh/17/

It supports hiding 3,4,5 if you emptied 2.

```
realname <input id="1" type="text"/><br> <!-- ID 1 inserted -->
username <input id="2" type="text"/><br>
place  <input id="3" type="text"/><br>
category <input id="4" type="text"/><br>
5+6=<input id="5" type="text"/><br>

$('#2').hide();
$('#3').hide();
$('#4').hide();
$('#5').hide();
max = 5;

$("input").keyup(function () {
    value = $(this).val();   
    id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));   
    nextid = id + 1;   
    if(value) {
        $('#' + nextid).show().keyup();
    } else {
        for(i = nextid; i <= max; i++){
            $('#' + i).hide();
        }
    }
});
```